# How can I make a VS console app on the Mac OS runnable without VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a Visual Studio console app on Mac OS. How can I package this up so that I can make it into an executable that I can click on to make it run?

Would appreciate some advice on this or some pointers as to where I can start to look.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio on Mac? And do you want the executable to run on mac or windows?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community on the Mac and would like my console app to run on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net core is the answer.

Create .net core console app and make sure that .net core framework is installed on macOS.

For packaging you can use any regular packaging techniques.